# GPG stops doing anything on Mac

Tags: command-line, mac, gnupg, homebrew

Twice now GPG has completely stopped working for me after some time (days or weeks) of not using it. When trying to use it, no errors show up and it simply sits and does nothing until i use ctrl-c to stop it. Looks like this:

```
➜ gpg -k
^C
gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting
```

It behaves the same way for any other command I've tested.

The first time it happened I had recently had a crash and thought that may have caused the error. I tried restarting, reinstalling and plenty of solutions to seemingly related problems, but the only thing which actually worked was uninstalling GPG with homebrew, deleting (moving) the whole ~/.gnupg directory and then reinstalling GPG. It then worked as normal, and since the only data I had were some test keys and signatures I didn't much care about losing all my data.

It has now happened again a second time and I have keys which I don't want to lose so I'm looking for a better solution.

With full debugging the output looks like this:

```
➜ gpg -k --debug-level 9 --debug-all
gpg: reading options from '[cmdline]'
gpg: reading options from '/Users/markusvidefors/.gnupg/common.conf'
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: enabled compatibility flags:
gpg: DBG: [no clock] start
gpg: using pgp trust model
^C
gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have had the same issue, this was due to the existence of .lock file in my
~/.gnupg/public-keys.d folder

If you remove the *.lock files it will work again.

```
rm -rf ~/.gnupg/*.lock
rm -rf ~/.gnupg/public-keys.d/*.lock
```

This can happen when your mac crashes.

Comment: I had the same after migrating to new machine. One note - for some reason I was unable to simply `rm` some of the lock file - I had to rename it first.

Comment: I noticed that my `git commit` hangs forever. (I'm usig ssh with yubikey gpg-agent) And also `gpg -k | gpg --list-keys` and several other `gpg` commands (`gpg --version` e.g. was fine). Luckily i found a `~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_keyboxd_sentinel.lock` which blocked everything with gpg. I'm not sure, but the filename  almost sound like a "mac has crashed" Thanks https://superuser.com/users/1853513/youssef-medaghri-alaoui